# Como criar um filtro de pesquisa para uma String Tridimensional?

Tags: java

Tenho uma `ArrayList` do tipo `String` Tridimensional:

```
String[][]
```

E gostaria de fazer um sistema de pesquisa que filtra os valores, exemplo:

```
String[][] table = {{"Ronaldo","32","Atacante","Sao Paulo"},
                    {"Cristiano","25","Meio Campo","Curitiba"},
                    {"Marcos","27","Goleiro","Ponte Preta"};
```

Bom, supomos que tenha uma pagina de pesquisa com os campos "Nome", "Idade", "Posição em Campo" e "Time que Joga", o usuario vai e preenche apenas os campos Idade e Posição e gostaria de fazer um sistema de pesquisa que apresentasse todos os resultados que contem os respectivos parametros, é possivel?

Comment: Você está utilizando JAVA 8?

Comment: String tridimensional? não quererá dizer, `array` de `arrays`?

Comment: Bom, no curso que eu estava acompanhando em videos ele dizia que era String tridimensional, esta errado?

Answer (score 0):

Jeiferson, nós chamamo isso de matriz. Um vetor de vetores. Tridimensional seria String[][][].

*Mas, respondendo sua pergunta, é possível sim. Basta você percorrer a matriz em busca do que precisa. Sugiro que utilize algum método de pesquisa como Busca Binária, isso irá otimizar a sua busca.*

Porém, acho que a pergunta correta seria: "Esta é a melhor estrutura de dados para fazer isso?"

Eu não sei qual a origem destes dados, mas se tiverem vindo de um banco de dados, considere usar algum framework de [ORM](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapeamento_objeto-relacional). Eu sugiro [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/).

Comment: OK, vou tentar fazer, se tiver duvida eu comento aqui...