# Como pesquiso um valor dentro de uma String?

Tags: java, string

Eu criei um `EditText` para o usuário digitar um valor, e assim que ele clicar no botão procurar na `String` o valor por ele digitado, mas gostaria de saber como pesquiso algum valor dentro da `String`!

Comment: Você quer saber apenas se existe o valor dentro da *string*? Como está seu código?

Comment: Bom, eu tenho um EditText que vai ser usado para coletar a palavra chave, e possuo uma string assim: String[][] table = {{"Cristiano","32","Italia"}};

Comment: Você já não fez esta pergunta? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49276/como-criar-um-filtro-de-pesquisa-para-uma-string-tridimensional

Comment: Nao, essa pergunta refere a criar um filtro para apresentar resultados, eu apenas estou perguntando como pesquisar algum valor em uma String!

Comment: Mas você colocou um *array* de *string*, igual você tinha feito na outra pergunta.

Comment: So me auxilia na minha pergunta por favor, apenas procurar um valor dentro de uma String!

Comment: Por favor, edite sua pergunta! Faça-a direito.

Comment: @Victor ja me ajudou, pode fechar o post!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Primeiramente, parece que você não sabe exatamente o que é uma `String`. Isso é uma `String`:

```
String
```

Isso NÃO É uma `String`:

```
String[]
```

Isso também NÃO É uma `String`:

```
String[][]
```

Ok, então o que é um `String[]` e um `String[][]`?

Um `String[]` é um *array* de `String`s. Ou seja, uma sequência de `String`s. O `[]` denota que trata-se de um *array*.

Desta forma `int[]` é um *array* de inteiros, `Thread[]` é um *array* de `Thread`s e `Batata[]` é um *array* de batatas.

E então, o que é `String[][]`? A resposta é que isso é um *array* de *arrays* de `String`s!

Uma forma de declarar um *array* é assim:

```
String[] meuArray = {"Pedro", "Carlos", "Maria"};
```

Isso declara um array com três posições, contendo as `String`s `"Pedro"`, `"Carlos"` e `"Maria"`, respectivamente. Para acessar os elementos do *array*, você usa a seguinte sintaxe:

```
String elemento = meuArray[0]; // O resultado é "Pedro".
```

Lembre-se que o primeiro elemento do *array* está na posição zero. Isso significa que o último estará na posição `meuArray.length - 1`. Você usa o `meuArray.length` para obter o tamanho do array. Ou seja, o último índice corresponde ao tamanho do *array* menos um.

Matrizes (indexadas por dois índices, tipicamente linha e coluna) são frequentemente representadas em java como *arrays* de *arrays*. Desta forma, e possível utilizar-se o primeiro índice para indexar a linha e o segundo a coluna. O motivo disso é que uma vez que a matriz é um *array* de *array* de `String`s, ao indexar-se um elemento dela, o resultado é um *array* de `String`s. Ao indexar-se uma segunda vez, o resultado é `String`.

Assim, você pode declarar uma matriz de `String`s assim:

```
String[][] table = {{"Cristiano", "32", "Italia"}, {"Marcos", "45", "Canada"}};
```

Ao indexar um elemento, o resultado é um *array* de `String`s:

```
String[] linha = table[1]; // O resultado é {"Marcos", "45", "Canada"}.
```

Ao indexar duas vezes, o resultado é uma `String`:

```
String lugar = table[1][2]; // O resultado é "Canada".
```

Portanto, é útil dizer que uma `String[][]` é uma matriz bidimensional de `String`s, pois temos duas dimensões. Embora na verdade isso seja um *array* de *arrays* de `String`s.

Da mesma forma, um `String[][][]` é uma matriz tridimensional de `String`s, pois temos três dimensões (e portanto temos que indexar três vezes para se chegar às `String`s). Na verdade isso é apenas um *array* de *arrays* de *arrays* de `String`s.

Assim, como saber se uma determinada `String` está dentro de uma matriz de `String`s? Assim:

```java
String[][] table = {{"Cristiano","32","Italia"},{"Marcos","45","Canada"}};
String oQueQueroPesquisar = "Cristiano";
boolean achou = false;

// Percorre o primeiro índice de 0 até o tamanho do array - 1.
externo: for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {

    // Percorre o segundo índice de 0 até o tamanho do array - 1.
    for (int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++) {

        // Se é o que queria encontrar, marca que achou.
        if (oQueQueroPesquisar.equals(table[i][j])) {
            achou = true;
            break externo; // Sai do laço. Não apenas do interno, do externo também.
        }
    }
}

if (achou) {
    System.out.println("Achei");
} else {
    System.out.println("Não achei");
}
```

O método `equals` é usado para verificar se dois objetos são iguais. Neste caso, ele é usado para verificar se a `String` da matriz e a `String` a procurar são iguais.

E como saber aonde ele foi encontrado? É só modificar um pouco o código acima:

```java
String[][] table = {{"Cristiano","32","Italia"},{"Marcos","45","Canada"}};
String oQueQueroPesquisar = "Cristiano";
boolean achou = false;
int acheiI = -1, acheiJ = -1;

// Percorre o primeiro índice de 0 até o tamanho do array - 1.
externo: for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {

    // Percorre o segundo índice de 0 até o tamanho do array - 1.
    for (int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++) {

        // Se é o que queria encontrar, marca que achou e também aonde achou.
        if (oQueQueroPesquisar.equals(table[i][j])) {
            achou = true;
            acheiI = i;
            acheiJ = j;
            break; // Sai do laço. Não apenas do interno, do externo também.
        }
    }
}

if (achou) {
    System.out.println("Achei na linha " + acheiI + " e coluna " + acheiJ);
} else {
    System.out.println("Não achei");
}
```

Para saber se uma `String` pode ser encontrada dentro de uma outra, podemos utilizar o método `contains` da classe `String`. Por exemplo:

```java
String a = "Cristiano";
System.out.println(a.contains("Cris")); // Imprime true
System.out.println(a.contains("Bob")); // Imprime false
```

E podemos então usar isso para fazer buscas parciais ao invés de exatas. Por exemplo para pesquisar por `"Cris"` e encontrar `"Cristiano"`, basta trocar isso:

```java
if (oQueQueroPesquisar.equals(table[i][j])) {
```

Por isto:

```java
if (table[i][j].contains(oQueQueroPesquisar)) {
```

E então o código final fica assim:

```java
String[][] table = {{"Cristiano","32","Italia"},{"Marcos","45","Canada"}};
String oQueQueroPesquisar = "Cris";
boolean achou = false;
int acheiI = -1, acheiJ = -1;

// Percorre o primeiro índice de 0 até o tamanho do array - 1.
externo: for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {

    // Percorre o segundo índice de 0 até o tamanho do array - 1.
    for (int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++) {

        // Se é o que queria encontrar, marca que achou e também aonde achou.
        if (table[i][j].contains(oQueQueroPesquisar)) {
            achou = true;
            acheiI = i;
            acheiJ = j;
            break externo; // Sai do laço. Não apenas do interno, do externo também.
        }
    }
}

if (achou) {
    System.out.println("Achei " + table[acheiI][acheiJ] + " na linha " + acheiI + " e coluna " + acheiJ);
} else {
    System.out.println("Não achei");
}
```

Note que dentro do `if (achou) {` eu uso o `table[acheiI][acheiJ]` para mostrar a `String` completa que foi encontrada.

---

Ah sim, finalmente *array* e `ArrayList` são coisas bem diferentes. Não as confunda, ok?

E também "String multi-valores" não existe. O que existe é *array* de `String`s.

---

Em C, C++, C#, Java, Javascript e linguagens semelhantes, o laço `for` tem quatro partes: Uma instrução de inicialização, uma condição de entrada, uma instrução de incremento e um corpo. Sua estrutura é a seguinte:

```
for (<instrução de inicialização>; <condição de entrada>; <instrução de incremento>) {
    <corpo>
}
```

O laço é executado da seguinte forma:

1. A instrução de inicialização é executada.
2. A condição de entrada é avaliada. Se for falsa, nada mais executará no laço.
3. Se a condição de entrada for verdadeira, o corpo é executado.
4. A instrução de incremento é executada.
5. Vá para o passo 2 e continue por quantas vezes forem necessárias.

Talvez você tenha notado que essa forma de executar não é muito diferente do laço `while`. De fato, o laço `for` nada mais é do que um `while` enfeitado. Por exemplo, este laço `for`:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    // Corpo
}
```

É quase equivalente a este `while`:

```java
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < array.length) {
        // Corpo
        i++;
    }
}
```

A única diferença que faz ele ser "quase equivalente" ao invés de "perfeitamente equivalente" é que a execução de uma instrução `continue` dentro do `for` tem que executar a instrução de incremento, o que não ocorre no `while`. No caso do `break`, o comportamento também é idêntico. Tirando este pequeno detalhe do `continue`, o laço `for` acima é equivalente ao `while`.

Além disso, embora seja incomum, o `for` não precisa necessariamente usar índices. Por exemplo:

```java
for (Elemento e = lista.getPrimeiroElemento(); e != null; e = e.procurarProximoElemento()) {
    // Corpo.
}
```

No java, a partir da versão 5, existe uma segunda forma válida para o laço `for`:

```
for (<Declaração de variável> : <conjunto de elementos>) {
    <corpo>
}
```

Esta forma é oficialmente chamada de *enhanced-for*, que pode ser traduzido para o português como *for aprimorado*. Há também quem chame ela de *for-each* e é especialmente útil para percorrer *arrays*. O conjunto de elementos deve ser um *array* ou alguma coisa que implemente a interface `Iterable` do java. Vamos deixar o `Iterable` de lado (isso daí já é um tópico mais avançado) e focar apenas nos *arrays*. Por exemplo:

```java
String[] meuArray = {"Pedro", "Carlos", "Maria"};
for (String nome : meuArray) {
    System.out.println(nome);
}
```

Neste laço, na primeira iteração a variável `nome` será `"Pedro"`. Na segunda iteração será `"Carlos"` e na terceira será `"Maria"`.

A vantagem deste tipo de laço é que ele deixa o `for` mais simples. A ideia é que você não deveria precisar se preocupar com os índices usados para acessar o *array* se o compilador pode fazer isso para você. No caso deste `for` acima, ele seria equivalente a este `for` tradicional:

```java
String[] meuArray = {"Pedro", "Carlos", "Maria"};
for (int i = 0; i < meuArray.length; i++) {
    String nome = meuArray[i];
    System.out.println(nome);
}
```

Usar o *enchanced-for* aonde possível deixa o seu código mais simples e mais enxuto, pois você não precisa mais se preocupar com os índices usados para acessar os *arrays*. Por outro lado, o *enhanced-for* é mais limitado do que o *for* tradicional e não pode ser aplicado em todos os casos, em especial não dá para substituir o *for* tradicional pelo *enhanced-for* nos seguintes casos:

- Se você precisa utilizar o índice para fazer alguma coisa a mais além de simplesmente acessar o elemento que está sendo iterado no *array*.
- Se você precisa estiver percorrendo os elementos do *array* em uma ordem que não seja apenas do primeiro ao último, um-por-um, um a cada vez. Por exemplo, se você estiver percorrendo de trás-para-frente, ou apenas a segunda metade, ou apenas os elementos nas posições pares, ou qualquer coisa assim, não será possível usar o *enhanced-for*.
- Se você estiver usando o *for* com uma finalidade que não seja percorrer *arrays* ou `Iterables`.

Mas, em pelo menos metade das vezes, o que você quer é exatamente percorrer os elementos de um *array* (ou `Iterable`) um-por-um, do primeiro ao último, um de cada vez e usaria o índice apenas para fazer isso e mais nada, e nestes casos o melhor é usar o *enhanced-for* para não precisar se preocupar com os índices.

---

Voltando ao seu código, e se houverem múltiplos valores no resultado que você queira?

Bem, primeiro vamos organizar um pouco melhor o código, e definir uma classe para representar o resultado da pesquisa:

```java
public class ResultadoPesquisa {
    private final int linha;
    private final int coluna;
    private final String palavra;
    private final String encontrada;

    public ResultadoPesquisa(String procurada, String encontrada, int linha, int coluna) {
        this.procurada = procurada;
        this.encontrada = encontrada;
        this.linha = linha;
        this.coluna = coluna;
    }

    public String getProcurada() {
        return procurada;
    }

    public String getEncontrada() {
        return encontrada;
    }

    public int getLinha() {
        return linha;
    }

    public int getColuna() {
        return coluna;
    }

    @Override
    public toString() {
        return "Procurei " + procurada + " e encontrei " + encontrada + " na linha " + linha + " e coluna " + coluna;
    }
}
```

Ou seja, cada resultado da pesquisa consiste de um conjunto de dados contendo a palavra que você procurou, a palavra que você encontrou e a linha e a colunas aonde a palavra foi encontrada.

Vamos primeiro modificar o seu código para usar esta nova classe:

```java
String[][] table = {{"Cristiano","32","Italia"},{"Marcos","45","Canada"}};
String oQueQueroPesquisar = "Cris";
ResultadoPesquisa resultado = null;

// Percorre o primeiro índice de 0 até o tamanho do array - 1.
externo: for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {

    // Percorre o segundo índice de 0 até o tamanho do array - 1.
    for (int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++) {

        // Se é o que queria encontrar, marca que achou e também aonde achou.
        if (table[i][j].contains(oQueQueroPesquisar)) {
            resultado = new ResultadoPesquisa(oQueQueroPesquisar, table[i][j], i, j);
            break externo; // Sai do laço. Não apenas do interno, do externo também.
        }
    }
}

if (resultado != null) {
    System.out.println(resultado);
} else {
    System.out.println("Não achei");
}
```

Como poderíamos então ter múltiplos resultados? Poderíamos colocá-los em um *array*. Embora esta abordagem seja possível e válida, ela trás certa complexidade para ter que controlar o tamanho do *array*. Isso é problemático porque não sabemos se antemão quantos resultados vamos encontrar, e o *array* deve ser criado já sabendo-se qual é o seu tamanho.

O ideal seria termos algo parecido a um *array* que aumentasse automaticamente de tamanho. Bem, é aqui que encontramos a interface `List`. Como o nome sugere, o `List` representa uma lista de elementos. No entanto, esta interface possui métodos especializados para inserir elementos no final (sem precisar saber em qual posição está o final), métodos para substituir elementos, métodos para excluir elementos (e excluir elementos em *arrays* é complicado, uma vez que tirar um elemento do meio de um *array* deixará um buraco e seria necessário deslocar os elementos posteriores). Enfim, é muito mais flexível que um *array*.

`List` é uma interface. Não podemos instanciar interfaces, apenas implementações. Temos várias implementações desta interface dentro da JDK para várias finalidades, mas duas implementações são particularmente importantes: `ArrayList` e `LinkedList`. A classe `ArrayList` é uma classe que usa um *array* por debaixo dos panos e ela se preocupa em fazer o trabalho difícil com o *array* (controlar o seu tamanho, aumentar ou diminuir o *array* quando necessário, deslocar elementos quando houver remoção). Já `LinkedList` é uma classe que se baseia em uma sequência de nós aonde cada nó conhece o próximo e o anterior. Na maioria dos casos você vai querer usar o `ArrayList`, que ocupa menos memória e permite você acessar os elementos em uma ordem arbitrária de forma muito rápida (diferentemente de `LinkedList`, aonde você tem que percorrê-los desde o começo). Mas existem em alguns cenários, principalmente aonde o desempenho seria degradado pelos múltiplos deslocamentos devido às exclusões, você poderia querer usar `LinkedList` ao invés disso.

Então vamos colocar os resultados encontrados em uma lista:

```java
String[][] table = {{"Cristiano","32","Italia"},{"Marcos","45","Canada"}};
String oQueQueroPesquisar = "Cris";
List<ResultadoPesquisa> resultados = new ArrayList<>();

// Percorre o primeiro índice de 0 até o tamanho do array - 1.
for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {

    // Percorre o segundo índice de 0 até o tamanho do array - 1.
    for (int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++) {

        // Se é o que queria encontrar, marca que achou e também aonde achou.
        if (table[i][j].contains(oQueQueroPesquisar)) {
            resultados.add(new ResultadoPesquisa(oQueQueroPesquisar, table[i][j], i, j));
            // Não sai de nenhum dos laços. Apenas continua neles para encontrar mais resultados.
        }
    }
}

if (!resultados.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println(resultados);
} else {
    System.out.println("Não achei");
}
```

Em algum momento, você provavelmente vai querer percorrer a lista. Como fazer isso? Lembre-se do `Iterable` lá atrás? Pois é, a interface `List` tem uma superinterface `Collection` (que representa conjuntos de elementos, não necessariamente ordenados como em `List`), que por sua vez tem uma superinterface que é o `Iterable`. Um `Iterable` corresponde a um objeto que fornece uma sequência de elementos a ser percorrida.

Portanto, uma lista pode ser percorrida usando-se o *enhanced-for*:

```java
for (ResultadoPesquisa r : resultados) {
    System.out.println(r);
}
```

Quase sempre, quando você quiser percorrer os elementos da lista, o *enhanced-for* lhe será suficiente. Caso não seja, então você poderá usar o `Iterator`.

No fundo, o compilador transformará o *enhanced-for* percorrendo um `Iterable` em um `while`, que é o que você provavelmente vai usar se tiver que fazer algo com a lista que não dá para fazer com o *enchanced-for*. Neste caso você vai obter um objeto `Iterator` que lhe dará os itens sequencialmente. Este `for` acima é equivalente a este `while`:

```java
Iterator<ResultadoPesquisa> it = resultados.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    ResultadoPesquisa r = it.next();
    System.out.println(r);
}
```

O método `iterator` (definido na interface `Iterable`) cria o `Iterator`. O método `hasNext` do `Iterator` diz se há mais algum elemento a ser percorrido. O método `next` faz duas coisas: fornece o elemento a ser percorrido e move o `Iterator` para o próximo elemento.

O `Iterator` também tem o método `remove` que permite você remover o elemento que está sendo iterado, se você precisar:

```java
Iterator<ResultadoPesquisa> it = resultados.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    ResultadoPesquisa r = it.next();
    if (<não quero este resultado>) it.remove(); // O resultado r é retirado da lista.
}
```

**Atenção**: Chamar o método `next` após a iteração ter terminado causará uma exceção `NoSuchElementException`, nunca chame-o em alguma circunstância aonde o `hasNext()` retornaria `false`.

**Atenção 2**: Alguns tipos de listas e de outras coisas que implementam `Iterable` correspondem a coisas que não podem ser modificadas. Quando este for o caso, o método `remove` lançará uma exceção `UnsupportedOperationException`.

**Atenção 3**: Tentar modificar a lista que você está iterando, sem ser pelo uso do método `remove` do `Iterator` poderá fazer com que uma exceção do tipo `ConcurrentModificationException` seja lançada. Então, a menos que você tenha certeza que o tipo de lista em questão foi projetado para permitir modificações ao mesmo tempo em que ocorrem modificações, você não deve tentar fazer isso.

Comment: Matou as duas perguntas que ele fez com uma única resposta.

Comment: Só acho que o exemplo maior deveria ter `contains` e no finalzinho você podeira falar do `equals`, para dar maior visibilidade à solução.

Comment: @RafaelBluhm Concordo, mas na hora de escrever o texto não consegui bolar algo introduza os dois conceitos um de cada vez de uma forma que ficasse simples para quem está em um nível absolutamente iniciante. Eu até tentei primeiro explicar o `contains` e depois vir com os `for`s, mas acho que fica meio confuso já vir com um código que faz buscas parciais para depois vir com um mais fácil para fazer buscas exatas. Entretanto, no final da resposta coloquei o código completo.

Comment: Victor, poderia me explica detalhadamente como funciona um "for"?

Comment: @Jeiferson Feito.

Comment: @Victor vlw cara...

Comment: @Victor, me restou só uma duvida, e se caso na array tiver mais de um valor correspondente ao "oQueQueroPesquisar" como faco para imprimir os dois valores?

Comment: @Jeiferson Pronto

Comment: Victor, sabe o table[i][j], ele esta retornando apenas com o primeiro valor, o nome da pessoa, como faço para acessar o segundo valor, o terceiro e assim por diante?

Comment: @Jeiferson Não entendi o que você quis dizer exatamente. Usando o `List`, a classe que lhe dei e o *enhanced-for*, você já deveria ter o suficiente para você acessar todos os valores sem problemas. Entretanto, sugiro a você fazer uma nova pergunta com o código que você tem agora explicando direitinho a sua dúvida.

Comment: OK, vou fazer isso... É que ele só esta imprimindo um valor da array, não consigo buscar o resto dos valores, e acho que o problema esta nessa linha: resultado = new ResultadoPesquisa(esta pedindo 5 args, e eu não sei como pegar o resto dos valores, então deixei table[i][j], oQueQueroPesquisar, oQueQueroPesquisar, oQueQueroPesquisar, oQueQueroPesquisar, e consequentemente esta imprimindo meu resultado e 4 do que pesquisei) entendeu? Se não intender eu crio outra pergunta com a situação do meu código...

Comment: @Jeiferson O construtor da classe ResultadoPesquisa tem 4 args e não 5. Além disso, se você não passar os argumentos na exata forma como eu demonstrei, ele não vai funcionar.

Comment: Mas eu construí ele com 5, porque eu keria buscar 5 valores, ou não é assim que funciona? Eu não fiz exatamente igual a você, portando ele esta pedindo 5 args, tendeu?

Comment: @Jeiferson NÃO. Não é assim que funciona. Cada resultado representa um e apenas um único valor. Se você quer buscar múltiplos valores, então você vai acabar com uma estrutura com três laços *for* um dentro do outro. Dois deles percorrendo a matriz e um terceiro percorrendo os valores que você procura.

Comment: Entao pra min pegar o segundo valor da table eu preciso fazer mais um terceiro for? exemplo, se eu quiser imprimir a idade da pessoa, como faço?

Comment: @Jeiferson Crie uma outra pergunta porque já não consigo mais saber como o seu código está no momento, pois deve estar bastante diferente do que foi originalmente. O que você está precisando agora também deve ser bem diferente do que você precisa antes, então acho melhor você criar outra pergunta.

Comment: OK, farei isso... Vlw!

Answer (score 1):

Se a pergunta realmente é só sobre o que está escrito, o Java tem uma função pronta para isso.

```
String s1 = "isto é apenas um teste";
String s2 = "teste";
System.out.println(s1.contains(s2));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/Contains.java).

[Documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)).

Comment: Mas minha String guarda multi-valores, tipo: String[][] table = {{"Cristiano","32","Italia"},{"Marcos","45","Canada"}};

Comment: É i que eu estou falando, você não detalha sua pergunta, fica difícil responder. Não tem como saber exatamente o que você quer se você não escrever claramente. O que você está colocando aí, pra mim, é o mesmo que a outra pergunta.

Comment: Dexa keto cara...

Comment: @Jeiferson só para constar: Isso aí não é uma `String`.

Comment: String que guarda multi-valores? Cara, da uma lida, é so um array multidimensional de strings, e não uma string.

Comment: Me desculpe entao... Mas alguem poderia me ajudar a como pesquisar um valor em uma "array multidimensional"?

Comment: As pessoas podem lhe ajudar mas você já fez esta pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49276/como-criar-um-filtro-de-pesquisa-para-uma-string-tridimensional. É lá que você deve se concentrar com a pergunta sobre busca em *array* multidimensional. Talvez você não tenha conseguido uma resposta ainda porque as pessoas não entenderam o que você quer. Então você deve editar a pergunta e fornecer mais detalhas ou tornar sua necessidade mais clara. Você precisa de ajuda, você deve ajudar as pessoas te ajudarem.

Answer (score 1):

Isso é uma string de vetores/array bidimensional, onde pode ser acessado assim:

table[LINHA][COLUNA]

```
table.length    , retorna o tamanho da linha.
table[0].length , retorna o tamanho da coluna.
```

Agora veja se este exemplo ajuda:

```
String busca = "Canada";
System.out.println("Busca: "  + busca + "\n");

String[][] table = {{"Cristiano","32","Italia"},
        {"Marcos","45","Canada"}};

for(int i=0;i < table.length;i++){ // Percorre as linhas
    for(int j=0;j < table[i].length;j++){ // Percorre as colunas

        // Verifica se a busca é igual ao texto em questão
        if(busca.equals(table[i][j]) == true){
            System.out.println("Nome: "  + table[i][0]);
            System.out.println("Idade: " + table[i][1]);
            System.out.println("País: "  + table[i][2]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Nao seria `table[i].length`?

Comment: sim, corrigido :)

Comment: Josinaldo, to dando uma olhada no seu codigo e percebi que a String busca devidi o que ele vai procurar, ai modifiquei para ela receber o valor que o usuario digitar no EditText, mas esta dando erro, era pra ficar assim: String busca = etSearch; ele aponta que nao esta conseguindo converter!

Comment: isso é um exemplo, você tem que "adapta-lo" pro que você precisa, pelo que entendi você está pegando por um EditText, então seria(se eu não tiver esquecido) nomeDoEditText.getText(pega o valor da string).

Comment: Sim, fica nomeDoEditText.getText().toString();

Comment: o.O, certeza que não é so .getText(); ?

Answer (score 0):

É isso que você quer fazer ?

```
public class MinhaClasse {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String[][] table = {{"Cristiano","32","Italia"}, {"Marcos","45","Canada"}};

        String minhaString = "Mar";

        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                if( table[i][j].contains(minhaString) )
                    System.out.println(table[i][j]);
     }
}
```

Imprimindo:

```
Marcos
```

Comment: exato, obg cara, é que ainda estou com muita dificuldade em usar o for, ainda nao entendi a logica disso... mas obrigado mesmo ae!

Comment: Pois marque a pergunta como respondida, e da próxima vez tente ser mais específico.